# C# Execute Method every X Seconds Until a condition is met and then stop

Tags: c#, silverlight, timer

I'm using a Silverlight C# Button click event to pause 10 seconds after click then call a method every x seconds until a specific condition is met: Either x=y or elapsed seconds>=60 without freeziing the UI.

There are several different examples out there. I am new to C# and am trying to keep it simple. I came up with the following, but I don't have the initial 10 second wait which I need to understand where to put and it seems like I have an endless loop. 
Here is my code:

```
  public void StartTimer()
    {

        System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer myDispatchTimer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();

        myDispatchTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10); // initial 10 second wait
        myDispatchTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(Initial_Wait);
        myDispatchTimer.Start();
    }

    void Initial_Wait(object o, EventArgs sender)
    {
        System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer myDispatchTimer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
        // Stop the timer, replace the tick handler, and restart with new interval.

        myDispatchTimer.Stop();
        myDispatchTimer.Tick -= new EventHandler(Initial_Wait);
        myDispatchTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5); //every x seconds
        myDispatchTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(Each_Tick);
        myDispatchTimer.Start();
    }


    // Counter:
    int i = 0;

    // Ticker
    void Each_Tick(object o, EventArgs sender)
    {


            GetMessageDeliveryStatus(messageID, messageKey);
            textBlock1.Text = "Seconds: " + i++.ToString();


    }
```

Comment: Rather than `new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, interval)`, use `TimeSpan.FromSeconds(interval)`.

Answer (score 0):

Create a second event handler that changes the timer. Like this:

```
public void StartTimer()
{
    System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer myDispatcherTimer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();

    myDispatchTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10); // initial 10 second wait
    myDispatchTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(Initial_Wait);
    myDispatchTimer.Start();
}

void Initial_Wait(object o, EventArgs sender)
{
    // Stop the timer, replace the tick handler, and restart with new interval.
    myDispatchTimer.Stop();
    myDispatchTimer.Tick -= new EventHandler(Initial_Wait);
    myDispatcherTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(interval); //every x seconds
    myDispatcherTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(Each_Tick);
    myDispatcherTimer.Start();
}
```

The timer calls `Initial_Wait` the first time it ticks. That method stops the timer, redirects it to `Each_Tick`, and adjusts the interval. All subsequent ticks will go to `Each_Tick`.

If you want the timer to stop after 60 seconds, create a `Stopwatch` when you first start the timer, then check the `Elapsed` value with every tick. Like this:

Modify the `InitialWait` method to start the `Stopwatch`. You'll need a class-scope variable:

```
private Stopwatch _timerStopwatch;

void Initial_Wait(object o, EventArgs sender)
{
    // changing the timer here
    // Now create the stopwatch
    _timerStopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    // and then start the timer
    myDispatchTimer.Start();
}
```

And in your `Each_Tick` handler, check the elapsed time:

```
if (_timerStopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds >= 60)
{
    myDispatchTimer.Stop();
    myDispatchTimer.Tick -= new EventHandler(Each_Tick);
    return;
}
// otherwise do the regular stuff.
```

Comment: Thank you - That's great. Could you tell me where the command is to stop the timer when elapsed seconds >=60?

Comment: I've tried this and my UI freezes for the initial 10 seconds. How can I prevent the UI from Freezing (Sleeping), so that just the loop task sleeps for the inital 10 seconds.

Comment: The 10 second delay was because I left the `Sleep` in there. I've removed it. I've added code that shows how to stop the timer after 60 seconds.

Comment: Hello Jim and Thank you. I'm somehow still missing something. It seems as though the Initial_Wait requires the line : System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer myDispatchTimer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer(); I modified my code up above. I think also you Mean myDispatchTimer instead of the other references to myDispatcherTimer in the example you gave me. When I tried to use the Stop watch, it doesn'  want to recognize Private StopWatch _timerStopwatch; I must be putting it in the wrong place. I'm new to C#. Thank you!

Comment: @user2026601: Try `private System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch _timerStopwatch`. And, yes, it's possible that there are typos in my example. I don't have all of your code to test with.